# Jquery find element by attribute partial value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following elements

```
<li data-attr="sessionContext='test session'"></li>
<li data-attr="sessionContext='test session 12345'"></li>

// I want to get all elements with [data-attr=someContext*=] -doesn't 
matter someContext= value, but doesn't work
$("[data-attr]") // gets all elements, but not sessionContext only
$("[data-attr='sessionContext=test session']") // works but for single element only
```

Comment: Use the attribute contains selector *= properly. Check the jquery documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a selector, you can try this:

```
$('[data-attr="sessionContext=test session"]')     
// will return the element sessionContext=test session

$('[data-attr^="sessionContext=test session"]' )   
// will return all that begin with sessionContext=test session

$('[data-attr$="sessionContext=test session"]' )   
// will return all that end with sessionContext=test session

$('[data-attr*="sessionContext=test session"]' )   
// will return all that contain sessionContext=test session
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$("[data-attr^=sessionContext]")
```

^ will match anything starting with sessionContext

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.